# Selecting column values of a dataframe which are in a range and put them in appropriate columns of another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which is something like below

```
date,mean,min,max,std,metric
2018-03-15,3.9999999999999964,inf,34.0,100.0,cpu
2018-03-16,0.46403712296984756,90.0,40.0,inf,mem
2018-03-17,2.32452732452731,0.0,0.0,143.2191767899579,cpu
2018-03-18,52.8571428571428523,inf,0.0,100.0,cpu
2018-03-20,0.6928406466512793,45.33,67.96,inf,mem
2018-03-22,2.8675703858185635,,0.0,119.05383697172658,cpu
```

I want to select those column values in a row which are > 30 and < 300 that is (30 to 300) and put those values along with date in another column of a dataframe.

So I want to get the date, values from the csv and add it into the new dataframe at appropriate columns.Something like

```
date        metric       stat  val
2018-02-15  cpu          max   34.0
2018-03-15  cpu          std   100.0
2018-03-16  mem          min   90.0
2018-03-16  mem          max   40.0
2018-03-17  cpu          std   143.2191767899579
2018-03-18  cpu          mean  252.8571428571428523
2018-03-18  cpu          std   100.0
....        ....         ....
```

What I have done so far is

```
df_app = df.loc[:, ['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std', 'metric']]\
            .fillna(0)

df_app['percentage_change'] = np.maximum(df_app['mean'], df_app['std'])
```

But I can only get the maximum value in a row and not values in a range.How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = df.melt(['date','metric'], value_name='val', var_name='stat')
df = df[df['val'].between(30, 300)].sort_values(['date','metric'])
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = (df.set_index(['date','metric'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'stat'}))
df = df[df['val'].between(30, 300)]
```

---

```
print (df)
          date metric  stat         val
12  2018-03-15    cpu   max   34.000000
18  2018-03-15    cpu   std  100.000000
7   2018-03-16    mem   min   90.000000
13  2018-03-16    mem   max   40.000000
20  2018-03-17    cpu   std  143.219177
3   2018-03-18    cpu  mean   52.857143
21  2018-03-18    cpu   std  100.000000
10  2018-03-20    mem   min   45.330000
16  2018-03-20    mem   max   67.960000
23  2018-03-22    cpu   std  119.053837
```

EDIT:

If `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
df = df.reset_index().melt(['date','metric'], value_name='val', var_name='stat')
df = df[df['val'].between(30, 300)].sort_values(['date','metric'])
```

---

```
df = (df.set_index('metric', append=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'stat'}))
df = df[df['val'].between(30, 300)]
```

Comment: my date is already indexed..so I get a Keyerror: 'date'.Any workaround for this?

Comment: Fior first solution need `df = df.reset_index()` first and for second `(df.set_index(['date','metric']` change to `(df.set_index(['metric'], append=True)`

Comment: @SouvikRay - Added it to answer.

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()` for the line `df = df[df['val'].between(30, 300)].sort_values(['date','metric'])`

Comment: @SouvikRay - It means some data are not numeric. Waht return `print (df.dtypes)` of original DataFrame before apply first or second my solution?

Comment: @jezreal `Type
mean        float64
min         float64
max         float64
std         float64
metric       object
dtype: object`

Comment: @SouvikRay - It looks nice, index is `datetimeinex` ? `print (df.index)`

Comment: actually i am finding percentage difference between two dates say 2018-03-21 and 2018-03-20 and so I get  `mean  min        max         std metric       device provider
date                                                                          
2018-03-21  76.724406  0.0  11.111111  124.285789    cpu` and df.index gives  `DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq='D')`

Comment: @SouvikRay - So do you apply my solution in loop? And for some datetimes it failed?

Comment: I take two dates 2018-03-21 and 2018-03-20 and find the percentage difference after which I get the format you see above.

Comment: @SouvikRay - I test it and it working nice. This problem is only for some combination of datetimes? Or for all data? If remove `.sort_values(['date','metric'])` it working?

Comment: I test it with `df[df['val'].between(30, 300)]` for return empty DataFrame (all values outside range 30-300) and also working.

Comment: yep now it works! I had a string in the data for which the comparison failed.Now its works!

Comment: @SouvikRay - Super :)